# How do I get access to fields of a node that a menu item links to?

Tags: nodes, routes, 7

For example, a menu item links to node/5. How do I retrieve that node so I can get its 'description' field?

Comment: Lets say the menu item is `$menu_item`. Besides doing `node_load($menu_item['link']['link_path'].split('/')[1]` or something.

Comment: Why do you need that info there?

Comment: I'm creating a page hierarchy, couldn't figure out any method that was used before, decided to use menus to keep track of hierarchies. This way I print out child pages on a parent page using the menu. I needed access to the node to get the "Body" field so it would provide a description.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [menu_get_object()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!menu.inc/function/menu_get_object/7) function or the [arg()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/function/arg/7) function. One of these 2 functions should do the trick. If i get you right ...